# Push notification certificate : Distribution Vs Development

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I know it may sound stupid question, but does it matter if you use distribution certificate for the development? Because AWS push notification service does not take .p12 file generated from development certificate and I have no choice but to use distribution certificate. The reason why I'm asking this question is because I'm not receiving any notification from my iphone sent from AWS SNS console. It seems that my phone has no trouble connecting to SNS service since I can see it is subscribed to the topic I created and the log information outputting from AWS framework suggesting the green light (shows token value returns from aws service).

Comment: you can't use distribution certificate in place of development , since distribution certificate can't be used to test push notification . As far as p12 file is concerned : Just make your .p12 file without selecting the key. Import only certificate, it should work  .

Answer (score 2):

As of 2016, you can use the same cert for both development and production. This is mentioned in one of the WWDC 2016 videos [What's New in the Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/724/) Session 724. It's covered at the 4:20 mark of the video.